# Wait for Firebase data to load before rendering NodeJS page after forEach with Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, firebase, promise

I'm trying to create a page that loads multiple data sets from Firebase, and then passes them to the NodeJS rendered page. I'd appreciate some help in ensuring that this happens after the forEach iterations; namely, I'm not sure how to get the Firebase forEach iterations to be part of my promises.

Thank you so much!

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    var getBrands = brandRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot){
        var brands = [];

        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            console.log(childSnapshot.val()['name']);
            brands.push({'name' : childSnapshot.val()['name'] });
        });

        return brands;
    });
    var getStores = storeRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot){
        var stores = [];

        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            stores.push({'name' : childSnapshot.val()['name'] });
        });

        return stores;
    });
    var getProducts = productRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot){
        var products = [];

        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            products.push({'name' : childSnapshot.val()['name'] });
        });

        return products;
    });

    console.log(brands, stores, products);
    Promise.all([getBrands, getStores, getProducts]).then(function(results){

        res.render('index', { title: 'MStore Demo Portal', stores: results[0], brands: results[1], products: results[2] });
    });
});
```

Comment: see my answer - you can literally just move this code from backend to front-end, all you are doing is merging results from the database.

Comment: Are those `snapshot`s arrays, or is it a custom (even asynchronous) `forEach` method?

Comment: @Bergi, that's the built-in Firebase forEach function for the snapshots.

Comment: If it's asynchronous, how do you know when it is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks 99% OK

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var getBrands = ...;
    var getStores = ...;
    var getProducts = ...;
```

So far so good (didn't even bother copying the code, because it's correct

```
    console.log(brands, stores, products);
```

brands, stores and products are declared inside the `.then` callbacks, so regardless of anything, they'll always be undefined at this point

```
    Promise.all([getBrands, getStores, getProducts]).then(function(results){

        res.render('index', { title: 'MStore Demo Portal', stores: results[0], brands: results[1], products: results[2] });
    });
});
```

The only "issue" above is that results will be `brands, stores, products` due to your order of `getBrands, getStores, getProducts` in Promsie.all

However, you seem to think (based on the index) that the results will be `stores, brands, products` - either swap indices 0 and 1 in the code, or call

```
Promise.all([getStores, getBrands, getProducts]).then
```

a tip, if you're using a recent enough node.js, you can do the following

```
Promise.all([getStores, getBrands, getProducts]).then(([stores, brands, products]) =>
    res.render('index', { title: 'MStore Demo Portal', stores, brands, products })
);
```

Comment: this is a coding solution, but I think this code doesn't need to be on an API server, just move this code to the front-end!

Comment: this is a "solution" to the question - the only REAL part of the answer is that the `console.log` is not going to show any useful information, and despite the  0 <==> 1 transposition, the code is indeed correct - not sure how introducing `firebase-queue` answers the OP's question, at all

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and the shorthand at the end, Jaromanda! I can't believe I didn't catch that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is designed to be a serverless architecture. In the long run, you shouldn't need a standard RESTFul Node.js API server. You just need Lambda workers. Please see: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue

Put work on the queue and a worker will pick up the job and update Firebase. When Firebase updates, it will send your front-end the message. It's all asynchronous and should work well for almost any application.

There's nothing wrong with having an API server too, but really it's not needed. Unless you have a very good reason for having what I assume to be an Express API server, then you can ditch it.

It looks like all you are doing with this code is getting values from the DB, you can do this with the front-end instead of an API server, and merge the results on the front-end, it's much better to do things that way.

Literally, just take the code that's in Express here, and move it to your front-end app :)

Comment: `Literally, just take the code that's in Express here, and move it to your front-end app` that literally is not enough, there's a lot more to do than move the code in the question to the front-end app (while assuming the front-end app is javascript based is a good assumption, it's still an assumption)

Comment: @JaromandaX I stand by my comments/answer, if you remove the Express routing line of code, you basically could lift the code and put it on the front-end. I am a backend developer, but Firebase is designed to be a very client-heavy architecture. You answered the question directly, but I wanted to make a point about the bigger picture. Firebase is a called "serverless" architecture for a reason. Think about what that means.

Comment: it's just that looking at `firebase-queue`, seems like a lot of setup involved (I could be wrong though) - I'm not disputing your answer, I'm trying to learn from it :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I am an old-school guy, I do not like shiny things. However Firebase queue makes a lot of sense, and the Lambda architecture is the real deal. In general, I like to follow KISS, and in this case a standard RESTful API would *appear* to be the KISS way. But once you do a little bit of work with Lambda and Firebase queue, you will see the benefits. Firebase-Queue is the canonical way to do backend development with Firebase DB. A RESTful API server is *not* the canonical way.

Comment: Furthermore, TMK, Firebase can launch your app as well. You do *not* need an API server to serve index.html. If that question was in your head. When I first started with Firebase, I thought at the very least you would need your own server to send up the index page, and then everything else would be "JSON calls" to Firebase. But I think Firebase can serve up your html files too.

Comment: Thanks for your help Alexander! For now, I'm going to stick to doing this on the backend, but I'll definitely look into firebase-queue and/or moving it all to the front-end!